# Cloning a nav for responsive navigation

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, clone

is there a way to clone content (in this case, a nav).  I want to duplicate a nav and then use that duplicated content for my responsive menu.

Bonus: is there a way to only run the "cloning" script at a certain breakpoint?

Thanks

Comment: please provide code  you tried using fiddle

Comment: I have no code at all to show, just html, I've googled for hours to try and find something but the only thing I've come across is cloning a nav to populate a drop down.  I just want to clone the nav into a <nav class-"mobile0nav">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [jQuery Clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

It clones a given element. You can also pass optional parameter "true".

Comment: this is perfect, thanks a lot.  $( "nav" ).clone().appendTo( ".nav-mobile" );  now, is there a way to only run that code at a certain breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Use media Queries CSS ,So u give class ABC for regular Desktop view,and give XYZ for responsive.
XYZ will only work for small screen hiding Desktop view

Use link
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Just see this web site in Regular desktop view.And then make Browser screen small,You will see at the right side ,Menu becomes responsive ,using mediaQueries

http://wordpress.org/

Comment: yes, thanks, I understand how media queries work, I just don't want two nav menus (albeit, one will always be hidden) all the time.  I only want to invoke the cloning script when necessary, let's say, when screen size is 500px or less.

Comment: Use media query CSS like 1)Small Nav(responsive) will be always hidden,Display:none .2)When resolution is 500 or less make it visible. Do u get it?

Comment: i get it, but there will be two menus all the time, i think I've found something that does what I'm describing here: https://github.com/ten1seven/jRespond  , only run code at certain breakpoints.  thanks for your help